# trying to make a monty hall simulation

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Monty Hall simulation. The goal is to try and be able to run multiple simulations so that I have a large enough sample size.

```
x = 0
i = 0
if modeChoice == "Automatic":
    swapOrNot = input("Do you want to test Keeping or Swapping")
    tests = int(input("How many tests do you want to run?")
        if swapOrNot == "Keeping":
            while i < tests:
                i + 1
                cars = random.randint(1, 3)
                randchoice = random.randint(1, 3)
                if randchoice == cars:
                    x + 1
```

This is not all the code, but the only part so far that is not able to work. Python tells me that there is a problem with

```
 if swapOrNot == "Keeping":
        while i < tests:
```

Specifically, it has a problem with the first line, the if statement. I do not understand why this if statement does not work. The while loop is there with the main goal of being able to run multiple times.

I apologize if I was not able to provide enough information, I would be happy to provide more :)

Comment: That line is indented for no reason. Python definitely would've told you this. If you don't understand the error, then you really should go back to the absolute basics and learn Python from the ground up, as indentation is a very fundamental aspect of how Python is interpreted. In Python, indentation is absolutely 100% critical to get right, since it's what sets the scope of a given piece of code.

Comment: [Indentation Error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndentationError). Your if statement and parts afterwards are on a separate indentation level.

Comment: When you run that, there will be some messages output following `Traceback:...`. Copy from that to the end and paste the message. You should read it too.

Comment: missing closing ")" on ```tests =``` line

Comment: un-indent from ```if swapOrNot``` to bottom, by one level

Comment: @AbbeGijly good point; the indentation might just have been messed up from being pasted into the question, but that missing closing parentheses is absolutely going to crash the program regardless.

Comment: ```i + 1``` by itself doesn't change ```i```, consider changing to ```i += 1``` or ```i = i + 1``` (those are equivalent)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version, based on the comments above.  As a cosmetic change a space is appended to the `input()` prompt to make the user input more graceful:

```
modeChoice = 'Automatic'

x = 0
i = 0
if modeChoice == "Automatic":
    swapOrNot = input("Do you want to test Keeping or Swapping? ")
    tests = int(input("How many tests do you want to run? "))
    print(tests)
    if swapOrNot == "Keeping":
        while i < tests:
            i += 1
            cars = random.randint(1, 3)
            randchoice = random.randint(1, 3)
            if randchoice == cars:
                x += 1
print(f'ran {tests} tests, got cars {x} times')
```

(Obviously you'll have to implement "Swapping" to create an accurate model for the Monty Hall problem.)